# How to integrate without limits in SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, calculus

I am given `p(x) = 2ax^2 - b` and asked to integrate it twice, but I'm not given limits. However, when I just use `integrate`, I'm not given a constant of integration, which is crucial to the next step.

Since I don't have limits, using `scipy.integrate.dblquad` didn't work. Instead, I am importing `integrate` from SymPy and doing two separate integrals. This is what I have:

```
from sympy import integrate

x = Symbol('x')
a = 240
b = 160

f = 2*a*x**2 - b

g = integrate(f) 

h = integrate(g)
```

What I want to get is:

```
g = 160*x**3 - 80*x**2 + C
h = 40*x**4 - 80*x**2 + Cx + c
```

where `C` and `c` are constants of integration. My code currently produces the equations without the constants.

Comment: You can simply add the constants, like `c  = Symbol('c')` and `integrate(f) + c`.

Comment: what is sympy giving you? what does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note that SymPy does not include the constant of integration. If you want it, you can add one yourself, or rephrase your problem as a differential equation and use dsolve to solve it, which does add the constant (see [Solving Differential Equations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html#tutorial-dsolve)).

It seems that they did cover this in the documentation. One needs to add the constant themselves or reframe the question and ask a different solver!